# How to name the columns in BASH?

Tags: command-line, bash, csv

I am writing output of 6 UNIX variables into a CSV file. Yes,now I have a CSV file with all the columns that I want.But, I want to use those variable names as column Name/ column Header.

How can we do this in bash ??

THis is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/manoj/version_2019_logs/
for file in log_Job_*/manoj.log; do
set of commands

Var1="$Filename1","$ProcessType1","$TotalDuration1","$Initialization1","$MPEProcessDuration1","$TotalPartitionDuration1","$WaitPartitionDuration1","$MainPartionDuration1"
echo $Var1 >>OutputFile_Validate.csv
done
```

Can somebody help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the header line before printing the data to the file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

Header="Filename1,ProcessType1,TotalDuration1,Initialization1,MPEProcessDuration1,TotalPartitionDuration1,WaitPartitionDuration1,MainPartionDuration1"
echo $Header >>OutputFile_Validate.csv

cd /path/to/manoj/version_2019_logs/
for file in log_Job_*/manoj.log; do
set of commands

Var1="$Filename1","$ProcessType1","$TotalDuration1","$Initialization1","$MPEProcessDuration1","$TotalPartitionDuration1","$WaitPartitionDuration1","$MainPartionDuration1"
echo $Var1 >>OutputFile_Validate.csv
done
```

For the sake of completion, `bash` also has a [variable name expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#variable_name_expansion) feature, thus

```
${!Filename1@}
```

expands to the variable name

```
"Filename1"
```

and if `$Filename1` and `$Filename2` are set

```
${!Filename@}
```

expands to this space-separated variable name list:

```
"Filename1" "Filename2"
```

Unfortunately that’s not really helpful here.